# Qt app doesn't apply Kvantum themes correctly on Fedora

Tags: fedora, theme, qt, flatpak

So I've been using apps that use the Qt engine like: [`Prism Launcher`](https://prismlauncher.org/) or [`PeaZip`](https://peazip.github.io/) with the Kvantum engine to theme those app. And in most of the apps I have, while some part of it are themed correctly, there are a good chunk of part that isn't.

One example being Prism Launcher:

[image: problem]

As you can see, the right and bottom panel are themed correctly, but the big giant part isn't.

Now, most of the app that I'm using is running off Flatpak, so it might be a permission issue. But I've make sure to install `org.kde.KStyle.Kvantum`, set those app to have access to the Kvantum theme folder, and to set the `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE` env

[image: problem]